# HTML how to open a video when i click a button

Tags: javascript, html, mp4

So I want to make it so when I click the button I have set, the background will change to this mp4 file that will automatically play (with audio), but I'm pretty new to HTML so I cant get the button to actually do anything. This is the code I have so far, it's in the body section. I've tried using onclick with .innerHTML (like in the example below), I've tried different variations of that but I can't get it to work, I can't think of an alternative so I'm asking ya'll beautiful people

```
<p> Hey, ya like this clock?</p>
<p> Click this button >:)</p>
<input type="button" value="( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)" onclick="clicc()">
<script>
function clicc(){
    document.body.innerHTML = "<div class="section">" 
            <video>  
                <source src="ZA WARUDO.mp4" type="video/mp4">  
            </video>
        </div>
}
```

Comment: You are replacing the body of the document with `"<div class="` the rest is omitted because of the quotationmarks

Comment: Your innerHTML is a value, but it is probably failing because javascript thinks that value fails at the  "s" in section because there is no ;

Comment: @LucaKiebel so you're saying i should delete that bit?

Comment: @Danimal you only rarely need semicolons in JS nowadays, this isnt the problem here

Comment: @ONCE_AGAIN I'm saying you should sorround your HTML in a diffrerent set of quotes, like `'` or backticks

Comment: @Danimal can you please elaborate your first comment?

Comment: @LucaKiebel Did not know that. I always use em because I'm mostly c# and it avoids confusion, looks like there is a Unexpected identifier error.

Comment: @LucaKiebel I tried wrapping the HTML code with ' but it still doesn't work

Comment: document.body.innerHTML = "<div class='section'><video><source src='ZA WARUDO.mp4' type='video/mp4'> </video> </div>"  (semi colon optional here )

Comment: Dont forget to close your script tag

Comment: Can i also ask how can i actually scale this video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an issue with your use of quotations.
you can't create a string with "" and then have HTML attributes with "" as well.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function clicc(){
 document.body.innerHTML = "<div class='section'><video controls><source src='https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4' type='video/mp4'></video></div>"
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p> Hey, ya like this clock?</p>
<p> Click this button >:)</p>
<input type="button" value="( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)" onClick="clicc()">
</body>

</html>
```

Check this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/7pruecmh/5/

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how can I make it so that the video automatically starts playing when i open it? EDIT: nvm i just swapped controls with autoplay

Comment: don't forget the muted attribute so it autoplays on mobile.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is with the quotes and double quotes, here is the fixed js code bit:

```
<p> Hey, ya like this clock?</p>
<p> Click this button >:)</p>

<input type="button" value="( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)" onclick="clicc()">

<script>
function clicc(){
  document.body.innerHTML = "<div class='section'><video source src='ZA WARUDO.mp4' type='video/mp4'></video></div>";
}
</script>
```

If you want to use double quotes for everything you'll have to escape the ones that are not to define the html string, the ones you'll use to define the html elements attributes, like this:

```
document.body.innerHTML = "<div class=\"section\"><video source src=\"ZA WARUDO.mp4\" type=\"video/mp4\"></video></div>";
```